# X509 Certificate in a POST method

Tags: spring, rest, http-headers, x509certificate

I am building a **REST** service (using Spring) to be consumed by an application. It is a very simple REST, it only has 2 GET and 1 POST method.
I would like to **control who gets access to the POST method**, so i thought about **using X509 Certificates** to do the job, the problem is i am already using HTTPS with server authentication, and it seems Client authentication  during the SSL handshake is out of the question.

The POST method in question acts like a proxy and here is the method structure:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proxy/{pack}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> requestService(
            @PathVariable(value = "pack") String pack,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody byte[] body)
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        OutputStream writer = response.getOutputStream();

        //LOGIC HERE - USING CERTIFICATE IF POSSIBLE

        //PROXY STARTS HERE
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL_OK);
        HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(body);
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(post);
        byte[] result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(postResponse);
        writer.write(result);                   

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        return null;
    }
```

I am having a hard time trying to figure out a way of send/receive the certificate..
Is there any way of **attach the certificate to the HTTP header**?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can add a certificate to the HTTP header sent, but I would not recommend it.

It's a bad idea to think that 'providing the certificate within the HTTP Post' or in the HTTP header is enough to check whether the sender is allowed to execute that action or not. Anyone could send you the 'correct' certificate and would have access to your service. The sender needs to prove that he is allowed to execute an action and this is not done by simply sending you a certificate.

Either try to activate client authentication in the SSL/TLS handshake (and for this you need a certificate and the corresponding private on the client side), or users need to login before they call your POST method and based on the user you can authorize the action or not.